# Actualizar valor de un campo con Firestore y Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

Tengo una tabla llamada Puntaje, la cual tiene dos registros: score1 y score2.

En Android Studio tengo un activity de dos botones, en donde el primer boton guardará el valor del score1 y el segundo botón, del score2.

Lo que quiero lograr es que luego de apretar el primer botón (el cual creará el registro), al apretar el segundo botón cambie el valor.

[image: Asi queda el activity]

Una vez que realizo las acciones, queda así:

[image: Quiero cambiar el valor de cero a otro número]

Tengo el código del primer botón, pero no sé cómo programar el segundo. Cabe resaltar que en el primer botón registro los dos valores, por eso es que quiero que el segundo botón me actualice el segundo valor.

```
        int score1 = Integer.parseInt("1");
        int score2 = Integer.parseInt("0");


        CollectionReference dbPuntaje = db.collection("puntaje");

        Puntaje puntaje = new Puntaje(score1, score2);

        dbPuntaje.add(puntaje).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                Toast.makeText(prueba.this, "Score added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(prueba.this, "Score no added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hasta donde llegaste lo veo bien, los pasos a seguir serian:

1) Obtener el Id autogenerado por firestore para poder consultar o modificar los dato que agregaste. Esto lo podes hacer muy facil usando el `DocumentReference` que nos da el `SuccessListener`

```
puntajeId = documentReference.getId();
```

2) con el id ahora podemos hacer una referencia a ese documento y modificarlo usando `update`. te pongo el codigo que deberia ir dentro del onClick del boton opcion2

```
CollectionReference refNuevoPuntaje = db.collection("puntaje").document(puntajeId);
refNuevoPuntaje.update("score2",1).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully updated!");
        }
    })
    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Error updating document", e);
        }
    });
```